# Bigcommerce authentication get request only returns scope and code, context is missing

Tags: api, bigcommerce

I am kicking off the Bigcommerce app installation process by following the instructions given in this official documentation page https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/callback apparently I am following every thing. I have `https` Auth Callback url setup in the app configuration page

[image]
*NOTE: I am using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/docs) to tunnel my localhost to internet.*

When Install my app I receive the code and scope objects in the Get Request but not the context object.

[image]

Please help me with what did I missed ? and how I can get the context object ?

**UPDATE**

I tested it without ngrok and its the same.

Comment: show code how to get the access token.